# Flutter parse-server sdk unable to delete object

Tags: flutter, dart, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm building an app in flutter and using dart sdk.

I was able to successfully create an object from my app but I'm unable to delete any.

```
var obj = ParseObject('MyClass')..getObject(id);
var res = await obj.delete();
```

returns

```
result null

statusCode -1

error Message: DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error [404]----
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

var `obj` returned `ParseResponse` object. I had to unwrap it to `ParseObject` and call `delete()` method on it.

```
ParseObject obj = (await ParseObject('MyClass').getObject(id)).results.first;
var res = await obj.delete();
```